# When output log with DLTLog, the program crashed

Tags: c++, linux, logging, embedded-linux

When I used DLTLog to output log, the macro DLT_LOG crashed my program.Below is the key code for my log output. Does anyone know why DLT_LOG causes the program to crash?

```
void DltLogOutPut(LogContext context, LogLevel nLevel, const char* pFormat_, ... )
{
      char buffer[256];
      va_list args;
      va_start (args, format);
      vsprintf (buffer,pFormat_, args);
      va_end (args);
      DLT_LOG(context, nLevel, DLT_STRING(buffer) );
}
```

The strange thing is that when I change the buffer size to 1024, the program runs normally.

Comment: What is `format`? What does `vsprintf()` return?

Comment: `pFormat_` and ` ...` contain some variable parameters, such as:`"LogText = %s, nLogSize = %d", LogText,nLogSize`. And I think the return value of `vsprintf()` is not important, becase I have tried to use `vsnprintf( buffer, sizeof(buffer), pFormat_, args);` to replace this function, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I didn't ask about `pFormat_`.

Comment: So what do you mean by `format`? I don't quite understand what you mean by `format`.

Comment: I mean by `format` the `format` you yourself used in your posted _key code_.

Comment: I have solved this problem, and thank you very much.
By the way, the reason for the problem is that the DLT version in my compiling environment does not match the DLT version in the running environment.